# Asymptotics of $p_k$-adic valuation of the sum of the divisors of the $n$-th primorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

Given this product:

$$a(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+p_k)$$

where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number and which can be interpreted also as the sum of the divisors of the $n$-th primorial ([OEIS A054640](https://oeis.org/A054640)), is there a way to get an asymptotic estimate for $n \to \infty$ of the $p_k$-adic valuation of $a(n)$:

$$\nu_{p_k}(a(n))$$?

As expected, lower primes seem more probable:

\begin{array}{cccc}
  n&\nu_2(a(n))&\nu_3(a(n))&\nu_5(a(n))\\
1&0&1&0\\
2&2&1&0\\
3&3&2&0\\
4&6&2&0\\
5&8&3&0\\
6&9&3&0\\
7&10&5&0\\
8&12&5&1\\
9&15&6&1\\
10&16&7&2
\end{array}

After @Denis Shatrov first comment, and some numerical tests for $n \le 1000000$ here are some guesses:

$$\nu_2(a(n)) \approx 2n$$

$$\nu_3(a(n)) \approx \frac{3}{4}n$$

$$\nu_5(a(n)) \approx \frac{5}{16}n$$

$$\nu_7(a(n)) \approx \frac{7}{36}n$$

Comment: I guess, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\nu_2(a(n))}{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i} = 2$.

Comment: For a fixed prime $q$ , the valuation tends to $\infty$. Do you have a particular $p_k$ in mind which grows with $n$ ?

Comment: @Peter I was curious to know an asymptotic approximation of the function $f_k(n)=\nu_{p_k}(a(n))$, in other words a formula. I don't know how it grows.

Comment: @DenisShatrov how did you get that? It seems good from data.

Comment: 1/2 of prime numbers are of the form $4k + 1$, 1/4 are of the form $8k + 3$, 1/8 are of the form $16k + 7$ etc. So we expect $\nu_2(p) = x$ with the probability $1/2^x$. Although I don't have a complete proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using more standard notation: for any fixed prime $q$,
\begin{align*}
v_q\biggl( \prod_{p\le x} (p+1) \biggr) &= \sum_{p\le x} v_q(p+1) \\
&= \sum_{p\le x} \sum_{\substack{k\ge 1 \\ q^k \mid (p+1)}} 1 \\
&= \sum_{k\ge1} \sum_{\substack{p\le x \\ p\equiv-1\pmod{q^k}}} 1 \\
&= \sum_{k\ge1} \pi(x;q^k,-1).
\end{align*}
Since $\pi(x;m,a) \sim \frac1{\phi(m)} \frac x{\log x}$ for every $a$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$, we deduce that
$$
v_q\biggl( \prod_{p\le x} (p+1) \biggr) \sim \sum_{k\ge1} \frac1{\phi(q^k)} \frac x{\log x} = \sum_{k\ge1} \frac1{q^{k-1}(q-1)} \frac x{\log x} = \frac{q}{(q-1)^2} \frac x{\log x}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you give a reference for "$\pi(x;m,a) \sim \frac1{\phi(m)} \frac x{\log x}$ for every $a$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$"?

Comment: That's the "prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions". Thanks for correcting my calculation btw :)

Comment: Why $\sum_{k \ge 1}\pi(x, q^k, - 1) \sim \sum_{k\ge1} \frac1{\phi(q^k)} \frac x{\log x}$? If there were a finite sum of functions, then it would be possible to replace them with equivalent ones. But there are an infinite number of functions $\pi(x, q^k, - 1)$. I think just $\pi(x;m,a) \sim \frac1{\phi(m)} \frac x{\log x}
  $ is not enough for proof.

Comment: Certainly one needs to include the standard error terms to make the argument rigorous, but there are no problems that arise when doing so. Note that the sums are indeed finite for any fixed $x$ (because $k$ can be no larger than $\frac{\log x}{\log 2}$.

Comment: @DenisShatrov The asymptotic formula is valid uniformly in $q\le(\log x)^H$ for any fixed $H>0$. A full proof is detailed in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The post is to determine an error term for Greg Martin's formula valid for all prime $q$. From his answer, we know that

$$
V(x):=\nu_q\left(\prod_{p\le x}(1+p)\right)=\sum_{k\ge1}\pi(x;q^k,-1).\tag1
$$

The convergence of (1) is of no issue as $\pi(x;q^k;-1)$ when $q^k>x$. By the prime number theorem for arithmetic progression, we have

$$
\pi(x;m,a)={1\over\phi(m)}\operatorname{li}(x)+E(x;m,a),\tag2
$$

where $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral and by Siegel-Walfisz theorem, for all $A>0$ there exists some $C_A>0$ such that

$$
|E(x;m,a)|\le{C_Ax\over(\log x)^{A+1}}
$$

uniformly for all $x\ge2$, $m\ge1$, and $(a,m)=1$, so plugging (2) into (1) gives

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|V(x)-\sum_{q^k\le x}{\operatorname{li}(x)\over\phi(q^k)}\right|
&\le\sum_{q^k\le x}|E(x;q^k,-1)| \\
&\le{C_Ax\over(\log x)^{A+1}}\sum_{k\le\log_qx}1\le{C_Ax\over(\log q)(\log x)^{A}}.
\end{aligned}\tag3
$$

In addition, because

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{q^k>x}{1\over\phi(q^k)}
&={1\over q-1}\sum_{k=\lfloor\log_qx\rfloor+1}^\infty{1\over q^{k-1}}={1\over q-1}\cdot{q^{-\lfloor\log_qx\rfloor}\over1-q^{-1}} \\
&={q^{-(\lfloor\log_qx\rfloor+1)}\over(1-q^{-1})^2}<{1\over x(1-q^{-1})^2}
\end{aligned}

and

$$
\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over\phi(q^k)}={1\over q-1}\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over q^{k-1}}={q\over(q-1)^2},
$$

we convert (3) into

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|V(x)-{q\over(q-1)^2}\operatorname{li}(x)\right|
&<{\operatorname{li}(x)\over x(1-q^{-1})^2}+{C_Ax\over(\log q)(\log x)^A}. \\
&\le{4\operatorname{li}(x)\over x}+{C_Ax\over(\log2)(\log x)^A}.
\end{aligned}
\tag4
$$

Because $\operatorname{li}(x)/x\sim1/\log x\to0$, we conclude from (4) that for all $A>0$, there exists some $B_A>0$ such that for all $x\ge2$ and prime $q$, we have

$$
V(x)={q\over(q-1)^2}\operatorname{li}(x)+\vartheta{B_Ax\over(\log x)^A}.\quad(|\vartheta|<1)
$$