# Compute limit of a function of the first $n$ prime numbers

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Just playing with the result in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4753507/573047), I am asking some help for computing:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n} p_{k}^{\frac{p_k}{(p_k-1)^2}}}{p_n}$$

where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number. The sequence computed at $n=16000$ evaluates to about $1.9180508$.

Comment: For n = 16000 I get about 1.918058...

Comment: @daniel Your value is correct. For $n=10^5$ , we get $1.91687292887\cdots$ , for $n=10^6$ , we get $1.91534543\cdots$ and for $n=10^7$ , we get $1.91528365958\cdots$

Comment: For $n=10^8$ , w get $1.9151127351\cdots $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aim of this answer is to obtain an analytic expression for the limit asked by OP. By a change of notation, we have

$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\prod_{k=1}^np_k^{p_k\over(p_k-1)^2}\over p_n}=\lim_{x\to\infty}L(x),
$$

where

$$
L(x)=x^{-1}\prod_{p\le x}p^{p\over(p-1)^2}.\tag1
$$

Taking logarithms gives

$$
\log L(x)=\sum_{p\le x}{p\over (p-1)^2}\log p-\log x.\tag2
$$

By the prime number theorem, we have

$$
\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p}=\log x-C+O\left(1\over\log x\right),\tag3
$$

in which

$$
C=\gamma+\sum_p{\log p\over p(p-1)}.
$$

Plugging (3) into (2), we have

\begin{aligned}
\log L(x)&=\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p}-\log x+\sum_{p\le x}\left[{p\over(p-1)^2}-\frac1p\right]\log p \\
&=-C+\sum_{p\le x}{2p-1\over p(p-1)^2}\log p.
\end{aligned}

Since the term in the last sum is $\ll(\log p)/p^2$, it converges as $x\to+\infty$. Plugging this into (1) gives

$$
\log L=-\gamma+\sum_p{\log p\over(p-1)^2}.\tag4
$$

### Numerical computations

Let sequence $L_N$ be defined by

$$
\log L_N=-\gamma+\sum_{p\le N}{\log p\over(p-1)^2}.
$$

Then we have

\begin{aligned}
R_N
&=\log{L\over L_N}=\sum_{p>N}{\log p\over(p-1)^2} \\
&<\int_N^{+\infty}{\log t\over(t-1)^2}\mathrm dt={\log N\over N-1}-\log\left(1-\frac1N\right).
\end{aligned}

From Mathematica computation, we have for $N=10^8$ that

$$
1.9150679<L_N<L<e^{R_N}L_N<1.9150684.
$$